# OpenCL kernel executes correctly only once

Tags: c++, kernel, opencl, local

I wrote a kernel and it executes correctly only once! 
I am trying to execute this kernel code:

```
__kernel void calculate2dim(__global int *g_idata, 
__local int *sdata, __global int *g_odata) {

unsigned int tid = get_local_id(0);
unsigned int i = get_global_id(0);
sdata[tid] = g_idata[i];
barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

for(unsigned int s = 1; s < get_local_size(0); s *= 2) {
    if(tid % (2*s) == 0) {
        sdata[tid] += sdata[tid + s];
    }
    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
}

if(tid == 0)
    g_odata[get_group_id(0)] = sdata[0];
}
```

This is the fragment of the host code (please, keep in mind, that it is a draft, not perfectly written code yet):

```
cl_int err;
size_t global;  // global domain size for our calculation
size_t local;   // local domain size for our calculation

int* data = new int[200];
int *res = new int[200];
int result = 0;

for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    data[i] = i % 14;
    res[i] = 0;
}

unsigned int correct;               // number of correct results returned
cl_mem input1;                       // device memory used for the input array
cl_mem output;

unsigned int count = 200;

input1 = clCreateBuffer(context,  CL_MEM_READ_ONLY, sizeof(int) * count, NULL, NULL);
output = clCreateBuffer(context, CL_MEM_WRITE_ONLY, sizeof(int) * count, NULL, NULL);

if (!input1)
{
    cerr << "Error: Failed to allocate device memory!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

err = clEnqueueWriteBuffer(commands, input1,
                           CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * count,
                           data, 0, NULL, NULL);

if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    cerr << "Error: Failed to write to source array!" << endl;
    exit(1);
}

err = 0;
err  = clSetKernelArg(kernel_av, 0, sizeof(cl_mem), &input1);
err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_av, 1, count * sizeof(int), NULL);
err |= clSetKernelArg(kernel_av, 2, sizeof(cl_mem), &output);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    cerr << "Error: Failed to set kernel arguments! " << err << endl;
    exit(1);
}

err = clGetKernelWorkGroupInfo(kernel_av, device_id,
                               CL_KERNEL_WORK_GROUP_SIZE,
                               sizeof(local), &local, NULL);
if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    cerr << "Error: Failed to retrieve kernel work group info! "
         <<  err << endl;
    exit(1);
}

global = count;

if(local > global) {
    local = global;
}
cout << "global = " << global << " local = " << local << endl;
local = 200;

err = clEnqueueNDRangeKernel(commands, kernel_av,
                             1, NULL, &global, &local,
                             0, NULL, NULL);
if (err)
{
    cerr << "Error: Failed to execute kernel!" << endl;
    return EXIT_FAILURE;
}

// Wait for all commands to complete
clFinish(commands);

// Read back the results from the device to verify the output
//
err = clEnqueueReadBuffer(commands, output,
                           CL_TRUE, 0, sizeof(int) * count,
                           res, 0, NULL, NULL );

if (err != CL_SUCCESS)
{
    cerr << "Error: Failed to read output array! " <<  err << endl;
    exit(1);
}

cout << res[0] << endl;

int x = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < 200; i++) {
    x += data[i];
    cout << res[i] << endl;
}
cout << x << endl;

// Shutdown and cleanup
delete [] data;
delete [] res;

clReleaseMemObject(input1);
clReleaseMemObject(output);
```

After the first execution I have the correct answer 1280 in the host code, but then (second execution and some others) I get something like 1073743104 instead of the correct answer. Maybe I forget to clean some variables or something?

Thank you!

Comment: g_odata is only set when tid == 0 (the first one) the rest wont ever set  it.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got it!

When you use this algorithm (Parallel Reduction Tree), you should keep in mind, that the number of threads should be the power of 2!

Otherwise (let's take 10 numbers) it will be like this:

Step 0: 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

Step 1: **3** 2 **7** 4 **11** 6 **15** 8 **19** 10

Step 2: **10 (3 + 7)** 2 7 4 **18 (11 + 15)** 6 15 8 **???** 10 //because number of active threads on each step should be even!